# check for an Array in a dictionary and return the UIImage but it's returning twice the same image

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary example : 1)

```js
var dict = ["A":UIImage(named: "A.png"),"B":UIImage(named: "B.png"),"C":UIImage(named: "C.png")]
```

And I have an array : 2)

```js
var array = ["A", "C", "K", "B"]
```

I want to check in my dictionary this array and return me an array of UIImage of the dictionary in the same order to my array and if it exist in my dict
So far I came out with this code

```js
var images = [UIImage]()
for key in array {
if let image = dict[key] {
images.append(image!)
print("\(image!)")
print("\(images)")
}
}
```

I noticed when you print images, the console show me: for example

```js
[ <UIImage: A>, {480, 236}, <UIImage: A>, {480, 315}, <UIImage: B>, {480, 315}]
```

it print twice A, A, B Images, but when I print Image I have just A,B,C, do you have an explanation ?
Please help !

Comment: I guess you have to insert `break` just after the `append` line.

Comment: @findall can you give me an example ? or correct my code thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code, I just tested this and it works:

```
let dict = ["A":UIImage(named: "A.png")!, "B":UIImage(named: "B.png")!, "C":UIImage(named: "C.png")!]
let keys = ["B", "C", "K", "A"]

var images = [UIImage]()
for key in keys {
    if let image = dict[key] {
        print(key)
        print(image)
        images.append(image)
    }
}

print(images)

for image in images {
    let v = UIImageView(image: image)
    v.frame.size = CGSize(10, 10)
    v.frame.origin.x = (self.view.subviews.last?.frame.origin.x ?? -10) + 10
    self.view.addSubview(v)
}
```

Flagging your question as `Off topic`

Comment: How can I have your v in an array ? I'm new in swift.. and thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Mams1101 What do you mean?

Comment: Because I want use images to display that in a tableview that's why, and I still have the same problem with images I really don't understand :((

Comment: I have no idea how you get it to print out `<UIImage: A>`, the double A shows different sizes, but you shouldn't only go for what it prints out, you have to actually show the images to make sure they are correct. You can put them in an array the exact same way you put the UIImages in an array.

Comment: But why image show just one A and images show me twice with different frame ?? I don't know if they is a way to concatenate image, because append in images doesn't work for me and that's weird :S

Comment: that's my print for images --> [Optional(<UIImage: 0x7fd1ce1882a0>, {480, 236})]
[Optional(<UIImage: 0x7fd1ce1882a0>, {480, 236}), Optional(<UIImage: 0x7fd1ce68fb40>, {480, 315})]
[Optional(<UIImage: 0x7fd1ce1882a0>, {480, 236}), Optional(<UIImage: 0x7fd1ce68fb40>, {480, 315}), Optional(<UIImage: 0x7fd1ce7d6d40>, {480, 312})]

Comment: And this is for image --> <UIImage: 0x7fa108fc2190>, {480, 236}
<UIImage: 0x7fa10b739390>, {480, 315}
<UIImage: 0x7fa10b8a7f90>, {480, 312}
<UIImage: 0x7fa10b94b200>, {480, 312}
<UIImage: 0x7fa10b122bc0>, {480, 329}
<UIImage: 0x7fa10bb419e0>, {480, 239}

Comment: UIImage(named: String) is an optional initializer, it can return nil. Just unwrap it inside the dictionary Like I did in my code.

Comment: it's work finally, because when it's doesn't find the image, the image above took her place !!! anyway thanks for your help, last question how to put empty when it doesn't find the image ?